# How to pass two values in jQuery function that takes data and send to server using ajax?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, jsp

So Basically I am trying to get values from an HTML element (Inside Html element Data comes from database using java) and then these values I am sending to another page using Ajax on onClick event. Here is that HTML Element

```html
<a href="#" onclick="getPosts(<%= sec.getId() %>, this,<%= sec.getDb_name()%>)" class="c-link list-group-item list-group-item-action"><%= sec.getSection() %></a>
```

function call inside onClick is getPosts(int, element reference, string) when I gave function only two param getPost(int, ref) it works fine (sending values to another page) but I need database names too that with a string value and then function didn't even work getPosts(int, element reference, string).

Here is the function body.

```js
 function getPosts(postid,temp,db_name)
    {
        $("#loader").show();
        $("#post-container").hide();
      $(".c-link").removeClass('active')
         $.ajax({
            url: "load_data.jsp",
            type:'POST',
            data:{pid:postid, db:db_name},
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                          console.log(data);
                          $("#loader").hide();
                         $("#post-container").show();
                         $("#post-container").html(data);
                         $(temp).addClass('active')
                     },
                     error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(textStatus);
                    }
        })
    }
```

I am calling this function using another JQuery method that is below

```js
$(document).ready(function (e){
     let allPostRef=$('.c-link')[0]
     getPosts(0,allPostRef,"eng_a"); // here i do not know how to call this function
})
```

getPosts(0,allPostRef,"eng_a"); here I also do not know how to call this function means if I am sending only two parms values inside a function so it works fine but i had to manually give string values and it is not getting data although I have checked db_name values is retrieving fine inside the element.

Comment: Does this helps you? `onclick="getPosts(<%= sec.getId() %>, this,&quot;<%= sec.getDb_name()%>&quot;)"`

Comment: Hi, put these jsp code under quotes i.e : `'<%= sec.getId() %>'` same for other.

Comment: Hey Swati, Wow.....It perfectly Works yaar,  Thanks a lot, Sorry for the late reply. Please can you describe to me how you caught this error?

Comment: @HamdanAli  If you see your browser console you will  see that error there syntax error ..etc .

Comment: I didn't know what's wrong with my code my console didn't showing me any error but thanks I'll look in again carefully.

Comment: @swati did you write this code again for testing?

Comment: no i didn't test that code.

Comment: @Swati Hi, Please check this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67403425/how-to-pass-global-variable-data-inside-ajax-load-data-in-jquery